# JPA Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, toplink

Hi I'm new to JPA and I'm having trouble understanding how it handles inheritance.

I have a specific problem I need solved without changing the DB scheme, but if you can't find a solution I would appreciate solution suggestions with a different DB scheme (Hibernate/TopLink solutions welcome).

If I was unclear or you need more information, please tell me so. Thanks in advance!

I have this database:

```
TABLE Fruit
Id Varchar (10) Primary Key
size Varchar (10)
fruit_type Varchar(10)

TABLE Apple
Id Varchar (10) Primary Key Foreign Key references Fruit.Id
Apple_Property Varchar(10)
```

So far my entities look like this :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="fruit_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.Char)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="fruit")

public class Fruit implements Serializable {

    @Id
    protected String Id;

    protected String size;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="apple")
//@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Id" , referencedColumnName="Id")

public class Apple extends Fruit implements Serializable {

    private String Apple_Property;
}
```

Currently I am able to persist Fruit objects without a problem..
Apple objects persist only when their Fruit object hasn't been persisted yet.

If I try to persist an apple object with an already persisted Fruit object :

```
Fruit fruit1 = new Fruit("1", "Small");
Apple apple1 = new Apple(fruit1, "red");
provider.create(fruit1);
provider.create(apple1);
```

I will get an error since JPA tries to create a new row on Fruit table with Id="1"
which already exists.

..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using JPA to persist a child object (i.e `provider.create(apple1)` in your case) , a record will be inserted to the child table and all of its parent tables. So `provider.create(apple1)` will insert a record to the Fruit and a record to the Apple table.

In your example , if  you only want to persist an apple object ,just call `provider.create(apple1)` is enough . It will persist the fruit reference inside the apple object too.

BTW , I suggest the Fruit Table 's PK to be a number type , and uses `@GeneratedValue` to mark the ID field of the Fruit bean. In this way , you can let the database to generate an ID for you and no longer need to  set it explicitly in the java code to avoid  this "ID already exist error" because of setting an already existing ID in the java code.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

But..

I need to be able to persist fruit1 and later on create an apple object made of this fruit1...

But I get a duplicate primary key error while doing so..

persisting fruit1 will write into table Fruit values (1,Small,Fruit)

later on while persisting apple1 it insert values (1,red) on Table Apple , but crashes while trying to insert again values (1,Small,Fruit) on table Fruit

Comment: When you first time persist fruit1 , you should persist it as an apple object instead of fruit object .In this way ,  records with your assigned ID will be inserted to both the fruit and apple table . Then , after you know the properties of apple object later , you retrieve the  apple object from the DB using the ID and update the its value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is working exactly as designed. When you use joined inheritance and persist an apple object, JPA will automatically insert into both the apple and fruit tables. You don't need to model an additional relation or JoinColumn in your entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use java inheritance concept while creating the db tables, which is somewhat not possible in this case. I could think one different approach for this problem. Have table fruit_type and fruit.
fruit_type(id, typename,desc)
fruit(id, name, type_id, desc) here type_id will be the foreign key.

Comment: It is possible in JPA .See :  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance#Joined_Table_Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and so far the only way I found was to query the parent and construct child with parent. Then remove parent and recreate both records.