# Join different tables depending on a column value

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I have a poor database design which I want to map with hibernate class annotations. I'm looking for a solution for the following behaviour:

When asking hibernate to fetch a container given an ID it should also fetch and set the `Container.content` field with an item of a table depending on the value of the `Container.type` field.

**How can I tell hibernate which table to join depending on the type field?**

---

Classes I have so far:

```
@Table(name="CONTAINER")
public class Container {

  @Id
  @Column
  private int id;

  @Column
  private IContent content;

  @Column
  private Type type;

  // Other columns
}
```

The Type value defines which table in which to look for the content field:

```
public enum Type {
  TYPE_A, // => Table CONTENT_A
  TYE_B  // => Table CONTENT_B
}
```

And following two tables reflecting the Type-Enum:

```
@Table(name="CONTENT_A")
public class AContent implements IContent {

  @Id
  @Column
  private int id;

  // Other columns
}

@Table(name="CONTENT_B")
public class BContent implements IContent {

  @Id
  @Column
  private int id;

  // Other columns
}
```

Comment: db table definitions might help also to get workaround. Single table?

Comment: Or are tables in db just as you have presented those entites `AContent` & `BContent` & `Container`  as three separate classes and do they have any relation in db level? Now you present a solution not a problem i mean.

Comment: Isn't this just table inheritance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919091/jpa-inheritance