# JPA - What Annotation to use for a base class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am a relative newbie to JPA, and I've read books (Java Persistence with Hibernate, Pro JPA 2 - Mastering the Java Persistence API), done google searches, but I have not been able to come up with a solution to the following situation.

I have a base class called History, that has all the persistent information needed to store the class's data members to a database.  However, the class has an abstract method that needs to be overridden in derived classes.  The derived classes do not have any persistence information of their own.  They exist solely for two reasons:

1. to uniquely implement the abstract method defined in the base
   History class
2. to persist the data to it's own table

The code below should make this clear.

```
@??? What annotation should I use here?
public abstract class History
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue   
   private   int    id;           // primary key
   @Lob @Column(columnDefinition="mediumtext", length=65535)
   protected String string;       // string containing history

   public abstract String foo();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="derived_history_1")
public class Derived1 extends History
{
   public String foo()
   {
      return "Hello";
   }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="derived_history_2")
public class Derived2 extends History
{
   public String foo()
   {
      return "World";
   }
}
```

I didn't think that @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) made sense, because nothing is being inherited in the derived classes that needs to be made persistent.

I tried @MappedSuperclass, but then the CascadeType.PERSIST and CascadeType.MERGE did not work when the derived classes were data members of another class.  For example,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="part")
public class Part
{
...

   @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="history_id")                                            // foreign key into history_part table
   protected Derived1 history;                                            
}
```

So I couldn't find anything that worked and fit my situation.
I hope I'm explaining this well enough that people can understand.
Does anyone know how to do this that's not a complete and total hack :-)
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919091/jpa-inheritance)

Comment: `@MappedSuperclass` seems to be what you want. If,as you say, that is not working then you need to ask a question about that.

Comment: I found this article that validated my suspicion that MappedSuperClass was the right way to go as far as the design.  https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/                   But I'm having a different issue in that the class is not being persisted, and that is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following annotations should work:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

Inheritance type `TABLE_PER_CLASS` makes inheriting entities to create own table and you also need to tell that `History` is also an `Entity` even it does not have table of its own.